# Partial migration to .NET 4 - Failure to find assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I have a C# application consisting of a single exe referencing many dlls, all were built with .NET 2. I want to integrate a dll built with .NET 4, so to do this I first need to rebuild the exe in .NET 4 and make sure everything works like before.

So I rebuilt just the exe with .NET 4 (full profile), replaced the old exe with it, and restarted the application. I get the following error:

`"Failure loading the types from the assembly 'blorg.dll'"` (where 'blorg' is a net-safe alias for the real name of the assembly, which is one of the old .NET 2 assemblies referenced by the exe.)

The inner exception is:

```
"Could not load file or assembly file 'file:///C:\\(...)blorg or one of its depedencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"file:///C:\\(...)blorg"
```

The FusionLog says:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location= C:\(...)\blorg
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/(...)/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\(...)\blorg.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/(...)/blorg
```

The dll in question is right there in the same folder as the exe. The entire thing works fine when I build the exe in VS2005 for .NET 2. The only change that happened was me opening the converting the solution for the executable (the executable has its own solution) to VS2010, changing the target to .NET 4, rebuilding it and copy-pasting it to the folder. Oh and it's in debug while the rest is in release. I've searched online for a while but I'm not finding anything that would help me diagnose the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you enable the flag that allows a .NET 4.0 application to load a .NET 2.0 assembly? There are dozens of answers on how to exactly that on this website.  Most are in the Related list.

Comment: You had no problem searching for it I see.

Comment: Your comment was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, some of these assemblies or their dependencies were mixed-mode .NET 2.0, so the fix was to go in the app.config and add the attribute "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" to the startup element:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```